# How to add cross (X) on a heatmap cells like with R language?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to add cross (X) on heatmap cells (depending on significance level, but the question is on adding the X).

Like in R-language (sig.level = XXX).

See the Python and R code used and the corresponding output images.

Thank you for your help.

````
# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, center=0, vmin=-1, vmax=1, square=True, linewidths=0.5, fmt=".2f",
            cbar_kws={"shrink": .65, "orientation": "horizontal", "ticks":np.arange(-1, 1+1, 0.2)}, 
            annot = True, annot_kws={"weight": 'bold', "size":15})




corrplot(cor(subset (wqw, select = 
                       c(fixed.acidity:quality,ratio.sulfur.dioxide))),
         # compute the p matrix
         p.mat = cor.mtest(subset 
            (wqw, select = c(fixed.acidity:quality,ratio.sulfur.dioxide))), 
         # significance level 0.01
         sig.level = 0.01, 
         # Method to display : color (could be corcle, ...)
         method = "color",
         # color palette
         col = colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", 
                                  "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))(200),


         )

```
````

[image: python matrix]
[image: R matrix]

Comment: Can you not just come in after the fact and manually draw the X's for cells where abs(corr)<threshold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy solution is to add a scatter plot with an X-shaped marker to cross out the unwanted cells.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(10,10)
mask = np.zeros_like(data)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

data_masked = np.ma.array(data, mask=mask)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data_masked, cmap="YlGnBu", origin="upper")
fig.colorbar(im)

ax.scatter(*np.argwhere(data_masked.T < 0.4).T, marker="x", color="black", s=100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The drawback of this is that the markersize (`s`) is independent of the number of cells and needs to be adjusted for different figure sizes.

An alternative is hence to draw some lines (an X are two crossed lines) at the respective positions. Here we create a function `crossout(points, ax=None, scale=1, **kwargs)`, where `scale` is the percentage the lines shall take from each cell.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

def crossout(points, ax=None, scale=1, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    l = np.array([[[1,1],[-1,-1]]])*scale/2.
    r = np.array([[[-1,1],[1,-1]]])*scale/2.
    p = np.atleast_3d(points).transpose(0,2,1)
    c = LineCollection(np.concatenate((l+p,r+p), axis=0), **kwargs)
    ax.add_collection(c)
    return c

data = np.random.rand(10,10)
mask = np.zeros_like(data)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

data_masked = np.ma.array(data, mask=mask)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data_masked, cmap="YlGnBu", origin="upper")
fig.colorbar(im)


crossout(np.argwhere(data_masked.T < 0.4), ax=ax, scale=0.8, color="black")


plt.show()
```

For `scale=0.8` this looks like

[image]

*Note* that for a `pcolormesh` plot or a seaborn heatmap (which uses `pcolormesh` internally), one would need to add `0.5` to the data, i.e.

```
np.argwhere(data_masked.T < 0.4)+0.5
```

Comment: Is there any way to use it with `seaborn` heatmap instead of `matplotlib` `imshow()`. Tried the first option but those cross doesn't seem align well.

Comment: Thnaj you very much. That's great! I would have never found it by myself ... I works perfectly with my sns heatmap. Not sure to understand everything in the crossout function, but I will take line by line and look for the corresponding explanations. Thank you again!